# Literature on contemporaneous analyses of languages that pre-date or are not influenced by Aristotle's "Categories" and the grammatici

Tags: parts-of-speech

Does anyone know of literature on contemporaneous analyses of languages that pre-date or are not influenced by Aristotle's "Categories" and the grammatici? For example, did the Chinese analyze Chinese on its own terms? Re. Sanskrit I've found only: Matilal, Bimal Krishna. The Word and the World: India’s Contribution to the Study of Language. Oxford University Press, 2001. Many thanks!!

Comment: There are few contemporary analyses predating Aristotle.  Very few.

Answer (score 4):

The first full linguistic analysis I can think of is Pāṇini's description of Sanskrit, written somewhere in the early fourth century BCE. Pāṇini is sometimes considered the first linguist, because parts of his *Aṣṭādhyāyī* weren't surpassed until the 20th century: he goes into great detail on phonetics, phonology, morphology, syntax, and more, with surprisingly modern insights.

Perhaps surprisingly, Pāṇini mentions in his work that he wasn't the first person to analyze Sanskrit grammar: he cites earlier work which unfortunately hasn't survived. But early proto-linguistics seems to have flourished on the Indian subcontinent well before Aristotle's time.

Answer (score 0):

We possess Old Babylonian texts analysing the verbal system of Sumerian, as far back as the third millennium BCE. This is very long before Aristotle or Panini.

Answer (score -2):

Pāṇini, obviously, and then the named predecessors of his he lists both in his own school, and in others (though their works do not survive).

Comment: This doesn’t add anything to existing answers.